# Reading numbers from a text file to an array

Tags: c#, text, io, readline

I want to read numbers from a text file to an array. The numbers are in one line.

- If I use `x.Read()` I get the ASCII code of the first character,
- If I use `x.Readline()`, I get a row, not the numbers one by one.

I want to use cycle to get the numbers one by one.

Comment: it's not unusual to read the line and the parse the line to extract the pieces you need. This often allows you to give better diagnoistics amd recovery from badly formed input data. All depends what language you are using though.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple, when you get the ASCII code you can easily convert it to the digit you want,
suppose you read a character (`char` ) from the file its '0', '1', '2', ... or '9' and you want the `int` value, you simple convert the `char` to `int` and subtract integer value of '0' which is 48. Like This:

```
char ch = x.Read();
int chIntValue = ((int)ch) - 48;
```

But almost all the modern programming languages have a `ReadInt`, `GetInteger` method or something like that in the `io` libraries they provide.

Comment: Thank you, but what can I do when there is a number with more digits and spaces? I want to write a sorting program from a file to an other.

Comment: For reading numbers with more than one digit you can use a loop to read all characters till it reaches a space, each time you just multiply the current result by 10 and add the new digit to it.
suppose you store the number in `result`, you should initialize it with 0, the for each `charIntValue` you want to add, the code looks like `result = result * 10 + charIntValue`

Comment: Thank you. I think I will do in this way.